# Best way to handle false unused imports in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, scala-implicits

Intellij falsely marked some import of Scala implicits as not being use.
Is there a way to prevent it from deleting those import when optimized them explicitly for a specific import and not prevent optimized import for the entire project ?

Comment: could you give an example? From memory, I think it happens for some implicit resolution imports, but I'm not quite sure of an explicit example to give.

Comment: This can be necessary if IntelliJ can't figure out that the imports are used. For example, https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions#automatic-formatting-of-sealed-traits-delegating-to-formatters-of-the-subclasses generates code with macros, so I'm guessing that IntelliJ will just remove some of the imports since it can't see the code that's generated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't, I had similar issues especially when using `akka` and importing the implicit execution context from an `ActorSystem` in some cases. I recommend defining the value instead of importing. One such example would be:

```scala
// Avoid importing the execution context like this
class MyActor extends Actor {
  import context.system.dispatcher
}

// Define it explicitly instead
class MyActor extends Actor {
  implicit val ec = context.system.dispatcher
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I was hopping for something more elegant something like just suppressing the warning, this solution can be ugly if you have more than a few implicits to import :) but this will do the work.. thx!

Comment: Yeah, you are right it can get quite messy, but unfortunately that's the only workaround I know :(

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: This will then become an unused val. But it looks like then you can add `@unused` above it and it does not show as grayed out. I personally also added a comment in front of it that it is actually used for the humans reading it! :D

Answer (score 14):

IntelliJ's Scala plugin now allows you to suppress this false warning on a project-wide level. That may not be appropriate for all cases, but it can help. Click the lightbulb then select "Mark import as always used in this project"

[image]

Alternatively you can add this directly to your code style xml:

```
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <code_scheme name="Project" version="173">
    <ScalaCodeStyleSettings>
      <option name="alwaysUsedImports">
        <array>
          <option value="models.slickless.synchronized" />
          <option value="another.import.path" />
        </array>
      </option>
    </ScalaCodeStyleSettings>
  </code_scheme>
</component>
```

IntelliJ usually stores that file at `.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml`. It may be a good idea to commit this to your repository so it can be shared.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't a fix and the problem appears to originate in the compiler itself.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7335 which leads to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8773 (reported in 2014 but no fix yet).